# Model based clustering equivalent to K means?

Tags: clustering, k-means, model-based-clustering

Is it OK to say something like this: "A model-based clustering with a hard threshold is equivalent to a k means clustering"? One of my instructors stated this in his slides, I kind of doubt this.

(For model-based clustering I mean the one based on a mixture of multivariate gaussian distributions, with totally flexible covariance matrix) I guess this statement only holds when identity covariance matrix is assumed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only do you need identical covariance matrices, you need them to be spherical. Otherwise "model-based clustering with a hard threshold" isn't a precise definition, and I'd for sure not say it this way even with the correct covariance matrix assumption, although I wouldn't say it's wrong, rather somewhat unclear.

Comment: I mean the "Identity" covariance matrix in my original question. But yes, I guess you are correct. It does not need to be the identity, but does need to be spherical. Thank you!